# Having issues using Streamreader to skip lines in C#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm having issues reading in a file using `Streamreader` in `C#`, where the **line breaks** in the file I am reading in are also being read into my program and causing issues further on in the code.

Below is an example of the file I am trying to read in.

```
Example,1,2,3
    <--- // Trying to skip these lines.
    <--- // Trying to skip these lines.
// MY COMMENTS.
```

Below is the code I am currently using to check for the line breaks.

```
if (line.StartsWith("//") || 
    line.StartsWith("\r\n") || 
    line.StartsWith("\n") || 
    line.StartsWith("\r") || 
    line.StartsWith(" ") || 
    line.StartsWith(Environment.NewLine) || 
    line.StartsWith(Environment.NewLine) || 
    line.StartsWith($" {Environment.NewLine}")) {

    // SKIP THE LINE.
    break;
}
// ADD TO ARRAY
```

> I have tried checking for `line.StartsWith("")` in the `if statement`,
>   but this results in no values being added to my array.

What needs to be changed for me to skip these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed
>   ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately
>   followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). **The string that is returned does not
>   contain the terminating carriage return or line feed**. The returned
>   value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.

This article may help: http://www.dotnetperls.com/empty-string

And try with `line.IsNullOrEmpty()` (assuming there's no other hidden whitespace on the line you read in).

In theory, every string 'starts with' nothing, so "" would be matched with every line/string you read in.

```
        if ("Hello, World!".StartsWith(""))
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        return;
```

Prints out the statement.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have an answer (several), I'd go with something that feels a bit "cleaner".

```
// Read all your lines:
string source = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path_to_your_file);

// Split them on new lines, ignore any empty lines
var lines = source.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()
                        , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

// Iterate over your `lines` here
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue)`? And do you use ´StreamReader.ReadLine()´? The returned string does not contain line breaks.